# How to export dc.js filtered data

Tags: d3.js, export, dc.js

I'm using [dc.js](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/) library to generate graphs and I would like to be able to retrieve the filtered data when filters are applied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create another dimension and then call `dimension.top(Infinity)` on it.

https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_top

You will need the extra dimension because dimensions do not observe their own filters, only the filters on other dimensions.

Then you can use e.g. `d3.csv.format` to produce text, if you need to.

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#format

Comment: Yeah the thing is crossfilter

Comment: Here's a [complete example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/download-table.html) including a download button. Explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37573744/676195).

Answer (score 2):

In the version 4 of d3.js `d3.csv.format` doesn't exist, you must use `d3.csvFormat` instead.

```html
const cf = crossfilter(data);

csvDimension = cf.dimension( x => x );

csvContent = d3.csvFormat(csvDimension.top(Infinity), [field, field2, ...]);
```

As Gordon said, csvDimension must be a new dimension in order for the filters to be applied.

Comment: Typescript will complain about type and returning true worked without errors `csvDimension = cf.dimension( x => true );`