# Export Data from dc.js dataTable into CSV

Tags: javascript, csv, dc.js, crossfilter

I have a data table done by dc.js and crossfilter.js, and i want to export that table to CSV file..

```
dataTable.width(960).height(800)
.dimension(by_id)
.group(function(d) { return ""
 })
.size(data.length)                          
.columns([
  function(d) { return d.id; },
  function(d) { return d.name; },
  function(d) { return d.gender; },
  function(d) { return parseFloat(d.GPA).toFixed(2); },
  function(d) { return parseFloat(d.Major_GPA).toFixed(2); },
  function(d) { return parseFloat(d.Math_GPA).toFixed(2); },
  function(d) { return parseFloat(d.English_GPA).toFixed(2); },
  function(d) { return parseFloat(d.Science_GPA).toFixed(2); },
  function(d) { return parseFloat(d.Humanities_GPA).toFixed(2); }
  ])
.sortBy(function(d){ return d.id; })
.order(d3.ascending);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a common request, so I've added an example using [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/). (There are probably other good ways to to a download from the browser, but this is the one I'm familiar with.)

http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/download-table.html

The key is to fetch all the data from the table's dimension using `dimension.top(Infinity)`. Then you can format it using `d3.csv.format` and download it using your preferred method. Here, FileSaver uses `Blob`s as the mechanism:

```
    var blob = new Blob([d3.csv.format(nameDim.top(Infinity))],
                        {type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8"});
    saveAs(blob, 'data.csv');
```

Comment: Here's an earlier [answer using download.js](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34793548/676195)

Comment: That was very helpful, Thank you very much.

Comment: In V5 of d3 its now `d3.csvFormat` instead of `d3.csv.format`

Comment: Thanks @Peter, sigh, yes, every answer I wrote before 2018 has been invalidated. :/

Comment: I found https://www.npmjs.com/package/dc-tableview to be very helpful. Github: https://github.com/karenpommeroy/dc-tableview

Comment: Oh cool, thanks @Alok! I didn't know about that. Looks much more complete than my [dc.datatables.js](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.datatables.js), which I probably wouldn't have written if I knew about dc-tableview.

Comment: You are welcome @Gordon! As always you are helpful and humble. Thank you.