# dc.js filtered table export using filesaver.js

Tags: dc.js, filesaver.js

I'm trying to export dc.js filtered table data using [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/).

I use the code below based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37501839/export-data-from-dc-js-datatable-into-csv/37573744#37573744) which is fine except it export all fields (but filtered ok) whereas I would just need table specific fields which are are only a few of the fields plus 2 calculated.

```js
d3.select('#download')
    .on('click', function() {
        var blob = new Blob([d3.csv.format(dateDim.top(Infinity))], {type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8"});
        saveAs(blob, DateT + '.csv');
    });
```

Is there a way I can point to the table rather that dimension?

Thanks.

**EDIT: Working code below**

```
d3.select('#download')
  .on('click', function() {
        var data = MYTABLEDIM.top(Infinity);
        {
            data = data.map(function(d) {
                var row = {};
                MYTABLENAME.columns().forEach(function(c) {
                    row[MYTABLENAME._doColumnHeaderFormat(c)] = MYTABLENAME._doColumnValueFormat(c, d);
                });
                return row;
            });
        }
        var blob = new Blob([d3.csv.format(data)], {type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8"});
        saveAs(blob, 'data.csv');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question.

It is actually possible to format the data according to the column definitions, by using some undocumented methods of the data table.

I've updated [the example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/download-table.html) with a radio button to choose which data to download.

Here is the code that transforms and download the data as it is encoded in the table:

```
d3.select('#download')
    .on('click', function() {
        var data = nameDim.top(Infinity);
        data = data.map(function(d) {
            var row = {};
            table.columns().forEach(function(c, i) {
                // if you're using the "original method" for specifying columns,
                // use i to index an array of names, instead of table._doColumnHeaderFormat(c)
                row[table._doColumnHeaderFormat(c)] = table._doColumnValueFormat(c, d);
            });
            return row;
        });
        var blob = new Blob([d3.csv.format(data)], {type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8"});
        saveAs(blob, 'data.csv');
    });
```

Basically, when the `table` radio is selected, we'll transform the data row-by-row using the same functions that the table uses to format its data.

The rows will be in the order of the original data, not sorted like the table. (And strictly speaking, [the columns may not be in the same order either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)). That would be a bigger endeavor, and might require new features in dc.js. But this works without any changes. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Gordon, This is is really interesting functionality. I tried but both options exported the same data. There are 4 references to 'table' are they all generic api "table" or do some/all of them refer to the var 'table' that we are getting trying to get the data from

Comment: Hmm sorry it didn't work for you. It does what you expect in the example page right? Table refers to the dc chart here but I also used it as the radio button option name. You probably don't want the `if` around it, that's just for the example.

Comment: It works now. The issue was that I didn't change the references to my table. Details in the edit. Is there also a way to specify Header names as by default it uses the names from the table definition. Thanks again.

Comment: I discovered that in order to retain Header names in the export just define the names in the dc.dataTable using the **{label, format}** method. [http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.dataTable.html](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.dataTable.html). I was previously using the original method.

Comment: Ah, good point, this method doesn't cover the "original method" where your headers are defined in the HTML - not sure how to infer the column names in that case. I've added a comment about that, or, sure, just update to one of the newer methods for specifying columns.

Comment: Please how can I export the fields which I have in my data-table and not those fields in my originals documents ( mongodb ) ... thank you in advance;

Comment: Hi @JeanDupont - I don't understand, I thought that was exactly the same question that was asked answered here.

Comment: I tried your code but it gives me my original documents ... :s i don't know what i should put in the index i

Comment: okay, i've removed the condition that was in the original example, please try again

Comment: Same result :s The csv file countain original fields in my database and not those in the dc datatable ...

Comment: Yeah I have no idea. This code definitely will not produce the same fields. It's clearly using the columns from the data table. Please file another question with a fiddle and I'll try to take a look.