# Javascript save dataTable into Excel using FileSaver.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, dc.js, filesaver.js

I am trying to export datatable to excel in javascript. I am using d3.js , dc.js and crossfilter.js . My code is based off of [this](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/download-table.html) example.

FileSaver.js is used to export Datatable.

I want to export my datatable to excel (instead of CSV). How do I do that?

```
   d3.select('#btnExport')
        .on('click', function() {
            var data = newTableDim.top(Infinity);
            var blob = new Blob([d3.csv.format(data)], {type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8"});
            saveAs(blob, 'data.csv');
        });
```

How do I change it to save results to excel ? Any Pointers?

Ref: [Export Data from dc.js dataTable into CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37501839/export-data-from-dc-js-datatable-into-csv)

EDIT: 
I get this Excel Warning, after I save it as xls.

[image]

I guess I can keep it as .csv.

Comment: Excel is fully compatible with CSV - in fact, I think they invented the format way back. Is the issue making sure that Excel opens the file instead of some other application? I wouldn't recommend it but I've sometimes seen people name their CSVs .XLS and Excel happily opened them. :-p

Comment: @Gordon . Thanks for response. I do get a warning message when I rename (I have added that to my question). Excel does open the file ok. I was hoping to avoid it.

Comment: I agree, it's a bad idea to lie about the format. I guess if .csv won't work for you, you could try a library like [js-xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) to produce real XLS files. I've never tried it myself...

Comment: thanks. I will give it a go.